# How to skip selected error reported by fortify source code analyzer?

Tags: fortify

While getting scource code analyzed by fortify source code analyzer if I want to skip selected catagory say "Poor Error Handling : Empty Catch Block" - is there any way to do that? In case of checkstyle report generator there is a way to skip selected error being reported. I would like to have that flexibility in case of fortify source code analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

First, open results containing "Poor Error Handling: Empty Catch Block" in Fortify Audit Workbench.  Then, find an Empty Catch Block finding, right click it and select "Create Filter..."

In the filter dialog, select the condition "Category matches Poor Error Handling: Empty Catch Block", and then in the Action section below, select "Hide".  Save the filter.

The first thing you'll find is all the Empty Catch Block findings have disappeared.  The filter is simply stored in the FPR at this stage.

To publish this filter as a matter of policy, choose Tools->Project Configuration and export your project template.  Save the file in the installation directory in Core/config/filters/ as specified in the readme file there.  If you do this on all your computers that produce scans, all your FPRs will share the same filter.

If you have a central Fortify 360 Server, you can import this project template into the server instead.  It will automatically be applied to any upload to a project of that template.

Comment: Is there anyway to skip it like ie. for sonar inline comment //NOSONAR. Don't get me wrong, filters are fine as far as people viewing reports are actually crediting them (if you know what I mean).

Comment: This is undocumented, but you can also specify the filter file to the scan with the "-filter" parameter. This may not work in all SCA versions, but if it works in yours then the rule will be identified and punched out before analysis begins.